# PlayerPrefs Not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey so im trying out unitys Playerprefs method and some how it wont save coins and when i close and exit the game it wont save it...

```
public Text CoinsText;
public int Coins;
public int clicks;


void Start()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins", Coins);
}
void Update()
{   
    CoinsText.text = "Memes: " + Coins;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", Coins);
        Coins += clicks;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins", Coins); to coins? I've never used player prefs, but I'm guessing it only returns a value?

Comment: Get int will load it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never assigning to your Coins.

Try this in your Start():

```
Coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins");
```

Note that the second value is only in case there wouldn't be a value saved.

```
public static int GetInt(string key, int defaultValue = 0);
```

Also, don't forget to Save all values before closing the program with:

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Comment: @FatihTkale Like FCin mentioned though, where is your PlayerPrefs.Save();? Is this just a code snip and you forgot to add it in?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should get int like this `Coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins");`

Then after you `SetInt` you have to save it with `PlayerPrefs.Save();`