# Type `int' does not contain a definition for `Text' and no extension method `Text' of type `int' could be found

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Im getting this error in unity, my problem is highscore, it doesnt work. I tried all kinds of videos on youtube but i think im doing something wrong in all of them. Also tried with Text highscore and also doesnt work. It says to me " Are you missing an assembly reference?"

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int scoreValue = 0;
    public Text score;
    public static int highscore;

    void Start () {
        highscore.Text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
        score = GetComponent<Text>();
        scoreValue = 0;
    }

    void Update () {
        score.text = "" + scoreValue;
    }
}
```

```cs
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class hazardCollisionFunctions : MonoBehaviour {



    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Platform"){
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            ScoreScript.scoreValue += 1;
        }
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            if(ScoreScript.highscore < ScoreScript.scoreValue){
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", ScoreScript.scoreValue);
            }
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `.Text` because `highscore` is an `int` and presumably `GetInt` will return an `int`.

Comment: just use `highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);`

Comment: Thanks! it worked. But how do i then save my highscore in that text object

Comment: what properties are in your Text object?

Comment: Should i use ScoreScript for highscore? Or do i need new script?

Comment: If i set ScoreScript to HighScoreText object it count me regular score

Comment: *`But how do i then save my highscore in that text object`* You need 2 Text objects, one for current score one for high score.

Comment: You only have one Text object in the question, and that's the one for your current score. You'd need a 2nd `Text` field to set your high score to it.

Comment: I have two text objects separately, should i attach another script to highscore? or can i use ScoreScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `public Text highScoreText;` field to your `ScoreScript` so `ScoreScript` can work with it.
2. Set `highScoreText.Text` to `"" + highScore` in `Start` so the text gets set appropriately.

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;

   public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {

       public static int scoreValue = 0;
       public Text score;
       public Text highScoreText;
       public static int highscore;

       void Start () {
           highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
           highScoreText.Text = "" + highScore;
           score = GetComponent<Text>();
           scoreValue = 0;
       }

       void Update () {
           score.text = "" + scoreValue;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Drag the high score text object into the `highScoreText` field of the `ScoreScript` script in the inspector

Comment: Thanks, it working in a way that it counts with score but doesnt save permanently highscore, any idea to fix?

Comment: @Matej You need to call `PlayerPrefs.Save`. [see this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742286/playerprefs-not-working)

Comment: Should i call it in a score script or in my hazardCollisionFunctions?

Comment: It would probably be best to call it after you update `PlayerPrefs`, after the `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", ScoreScript.scoreValue);` line in `hazardCollisionFunctions`

Comment: If you need help getting `PlayerPrefs.Save` to work, that would be good for another question since it's a different topic than getting text to display. Just make sure you include the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, cannot now, somebody devoted my question.. Thanks a lot Ruzihm!